# d3.js: modifyng links in a tree layout

Tags: d3.js, tree

and sorry for my bad english...
I'm using the example here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083
to build a tree diagram, but I changed the circles in the root's children with a rect.
Now the diagram is a bit messy because the I see the links go through the rect.
I want these links start and stop to the sides of the rect. 
I think I have to modify the code in the diagonal path generator:

```
    // Update the links…
var nodeLinks = tree.links(nodes);
var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
  .data(nodeLinks, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", function(d) { 
    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
})
.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", diagonal);

// Transition links to their new position.
link.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", diagonal);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
link.exit().transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  })
  .remove();
```

but I can't figure out how.
I saw the `diagonal.source([source])` and
the `diagonal.target([target])` methods in the API reference.
Maybe they can help me, but I don't understand how to use it.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is offset the start and end of the path by the width of the rectangles. What you need to modify is this:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
```

Assuming that `w` is the width of your rectangle, the new code should look something like this.

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x - w]; });
```

Comment: Hi Lars, doesn't your method just offset the point where one link ends and the other begins? I.e. They are still connected (at least that's what a small experiment seems to show). I think that  @MrBeboop was wanting the end of one link to be on one side of his rectangle and the start of the next link to be on the other side of the rectangle. I think that he was correct in thinking that the source / target methods need to be employed, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It's possible that the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915127/direction-of-link-orientation-in-tree-diagram-incorrect) may add some value as well.

Comment: @d3noob Not sure -- OP seemed to be ok with the answer though.