# Append links to side of rectangles in D3 tree layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I am trying to change each `path` so that they start from the right side of each rectangle and connect to the left side. Currently they seem to travel "through" the rectangles and have a start/end point somewhere inside the rectangle, not compensating for the size of the `rect`.

I have tried manipulating this code:

```
        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .source(function (d) { return { "x": d.source.y, "y": d.source.x }; })
        .target(function (d) { return { "x": d.target.y - 10, "y": d.target.x }; })
        .projection(function (d) { return [d.y + 0, d.x + 0];
      });
```

but that just ends in disaster but I believe the answer lies somewhere over there.

Here is a JSFiddle of the script as it stands http://jsfiddle.net/ra26wnbb/.

**UPDATE** 
I have viewed [D3 tree square node not in desired position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735995/d3-tree-square-node-not-in-desired-position) but I am not sure it will work with my text wrapping.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but your fiddle doesn't show anything.

Comment: Use google chrome maybe?

Comment: @barnacle.m could you tell me, what you exactly wants to display, I'm not getting appending links to side of rectangles in D3 tree layout, here what do mean by links???

And your code is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, after the work inside `wrap()` is done, you need to store the resulting height on the datum of the text: `d.height = 19 * (lineNumber + 1);`. That way, the height becomes available to whatever needs it. For example, you can use that to set the `rect` height from outside of `wrap()` instead of the `parentNode.children[0]` thing, which is better separation of concerns. Anyway, this is what `wrap()` ends up being:

```
    function wrap(text, width) {
        text.each(function (d) { // DIFF add param d
            var text = d3.select(this),
              // DIFF: use datum to get name, instead of element text
              words = d.name.split(/\s+/).reverse(), 
              word,
              line = [],
              lineNumber = 0,
              lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
              y = text.attr("y"),
              dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
              tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
            while (word = words.pop()) {
                line.push(word);
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
                }
            }

            // DIFF: store the height via the datum, d
            d.height = 19 * (lineNumber + 1);
            d3.select(this.parentNode.children[0]).attr('height', 19 * (lineNumber + 1));

        });
    }
});
```

Now that you have `d.height` you can use it to calculate the necessary offsets of the diagonal's endpoints.

```
    // calculate source and target offsets
    // d.height gets set by the wrap() function
    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .source(function (d) {
            return {
                "x": d.source.x + d.source.height / 2,
                "y": d.source.y + 150
            };
        })
        .target(function (d) {
            return {
                "x": d.target.x + d.target.height / 2,
                "y": d.target.y
            };
        })
        .projection(function (d) { return [d.y + 0, d.x + 0];
      });
```

See [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ra26wnbb/5/)

Comment: This is brilliant thank you. I don't think I would have figured this out on my own.

Comment: Can you explain how to achieve the same in D3 Version 4 ?