# Direction of link orientation in tree diagram incorrect

Tags: d3.js

Starting from the tree diagram example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8323795) I want to change the links so that the source and target locations of each can be altered relative to their common meeting point. My current progress point is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7fa9ce06684669b5a7964b928f11043d) (these examples are contrived to demonstrate the problem, but I believe it does so adequately).

This appears to be possible using the [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#diagonal_source) and [target](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#diagonal_target) assessor functions. I have therefore edited the original code for the `diagonal` variable from;

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
```

to;

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .source(function(d) { return {x: d.source.y , y: d.source.x}; })
    .target(function(d) { return {x: d.target.y , y: d.target.x}; });
```

Which has worked fine for the locations, but the links think that they are still vertical and as a result look like this;

[image]

rather than this;

[image]

I have tried altering the orientations of the x / y values in the diagonal variable declaration which only succeeds in orientating the tree links vertically.

I have also tried doing the same in a slightly more complex piece of code when entering the links, with the links appearing with the incorrect orientation again.

I can't help but think that I need to be including an additional assessor to account for the direction of the curve, but I'm darned if I can see it.

Starting code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8323795).

Adapted code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7fa9ce06684669b5a7964b928f11043d).

Many thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be completely missing something here. But but replacing:

```
.projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
```

with:

```
.source(function(d) { return {x: d.source.y , y: d.source.x}; })
.target(function(d) { return {x: d.target.y , y: d.target.x}; });
```

almost replicates the functionality of .projection, except for how the lines are interpolated. Instead, if you set the projection as it was originally and define the the x and y coordinates for source and target normally, the entire diagram is flipped from vertical alignment to horizontal:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; })
  .source(function(d) { return {x: d.source.x , y: d.source.y}; })
  .target(function(d) { return {x: d.target.x , y: d.target.y}; })
```

Giving:

[image]

Which still gives you access to the source and target assessors while maintaining a correct alignment, which I take as the goal.

Love your D3 site by the way, it's a great resource.

Comment: Perfect! Nice job. You nailed it! (and thanks for the compliment :-)).

Comment: Solved my problem